# Degree 2 Holomorphic Map Between Annuli

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Consider the annulus $A(D) = \{D < |z| < 1\}$ where $0 \leq D < 1$. I need to find all $D$ such that there is a holomorphic map $f: A(D) \rightarrow A(D)$ of degree 2. By degree 2, I mean that the induced map $f_*: \pi_1(A(D)) \rightarrow \pi_1(A(D))$ is multiplication by $2$ as these fundamental groups are just isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

I only know very basic algebraic topology, so I've seen the degree of continuous maps $\mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ defined in terms of path lifting. However, I'm not sure how to approach the case of the annuli on the complex plane. Intuitively, $f$ should somehow "wrap" around $A(D)$ twice, but I don't know to formalize this, let alone figure out which $D$ this is possible for.

I know that the universal cover of $A(D)$ is the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$, so I believe I'll need to lift something into $\mathbb{H}^2$ at some point in time. But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know a holomorphic map $p : \mathbb{H}^2 \to A(D)$ that realizes the universal cover? Once you have this, choose a basepoint $z_0 \in \mathbb{H}^2$ and identify $\pi_1(A(D), p(z_0))$ with $p^{-1}(p(z_0))$, by say path lifting. Then you should figure out what $f$ being degree $2$ means for a lift of $f$ to $\mathbb{H}^2$.